# How am I modify input value of a child's component?

Tags: angular

I have a page call person-input.ts and person-input.html

what I want to do is when inside AddPerson from person-input.ts
I would like to dynamically modifying the name-input component
so that set [focused]="true"

so the code will be from

```
<name-input [disabled]="isPersonDisabled(i)" autofocus [name]="personGroup.get('name').value" [form]="$any(personGroup)" [submitted]="submitted" (change)="onNameChange($event)" (textChange)="onNameTextChange($event, i)" autofocus></name-input>
                            </div>
```

to

```
<name-input [disabled]="isPersonDisabled(i)" autofocus [focused]="true" [name]="personGroup.get('name').value" [form]="$any(personGroup)" [submitted]="submitted" (change)="onNameChange($event)" (textChange)="onNameTextChange($event, i)" autofocus></name-input>
                            </div>
```

person-input.ts code as follow

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit,
    Input,
    ChangeDetectionStrategy,
    OnDestroy,
    ViewChild,
    ViewChildren,
    QueryList
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl,Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Person, LabelValueItem, PERSON_TYPE_PARTNER, BroadcastEventArgs, PERSON_TYPE_CHILD, FormControlDefinition} from '../../../../../_shared/models';
import { Events, DOBValidationMessages } from '../../../../../_shared/constants';
import { FadeInOutTrigger, AccordionTrigger } from '../../../../../_shared/triggers';
import { GenericBroadcastService } from '../../../../../_shared/services';
import { IStepHelper, StepHelperFactory, AppFormClone } from '../../../utils';
import { AppForm, HealthHistoryData, ApplicantDetail } from '../../../../../Shared_TOPS/models';
import { HealthHelper, GTMHelper } from '../../../utils';
import { NavigationStore, AppFormStore } from '../../../state-management';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { EmailValidator,MaxLengthLimitValidator,CompareDatesValidator } from '../../../../../_shared/validators';
import { AppRuntimeService, OlaBroadcastService } from '../../../services';
import { UIHelper } from '../../../../../_shared/utils';
import { ScrollToService } from '@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to';
import { ROUTENAME_COVER } from '../../../../../Shared_TOPS/constants/steps';
import { AppFormHelper } from '../../../../../Shared_TOPS/utils';
import { ContentKeys, SubModuleTypes } from '../../../../../Shared_TOPS/constants';
import { GenderIdentities } from '../../../../../Shared_TOPS/constants/gender-identities';
import { Genders } from '../../../../../Shared_TOPS/constants/genders';
import { Titles } from '../../../../../Shared_TOPS/constants/titles';
import { ApplicationConstants } from '../../../../../Shared_TOPS/models/applications/application-constants';
import { BroadcastService, ContentService } from '../../../../../Shared_TOPS/services';
import { ApplicationSource } from '../../../../../Shared_TOPS/models/applications/application-source';
import { PersonDetailsFormModel } from '../../../forms';
import { sha256 } from 'js-sha256';

@Component({
    selector: 'person-input',
    templateUrl: './person-input.html',
    styleUrls: ['./person-input.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    animations: [
        FadeInOutTrigger,
        AccordionTrigger(300)
    ]
})
export class PersonInputComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChild('divMobile', { static: true }) divMobile: any;
    @ViewChildren('personTop') personTopQueryList: QueryList<any>;

    @Input()
    public form: FormGroup;

    @Input()
    public appform: AppForm;

    @Input()
    public constants: ApplicationConstants;

    // applicants is simply passed through to is-smoker and isn't used at all in this file
    @Input()
    public applicants: Array<ApplicantDetail>;

    @Input()
    public persons: Array<Person>;

    @Input()
    public healthData: HealthHistoryData;

    @Input()
    public personType: string;

    @Input()
    public forceDottedLine: boolean;

    @Input()
    public submitted: boolean;

    @Input()
    public maxAllowedPersons = 1;

    @Input()
    public heading = 'Person';

    @Input()
    public addButtonText = 'Add person';

    @Input()
    public maxAllowedErrorMessage: string;

    @Input()
    public policyHolderAdditionalPlanName: string;

    @Input()
    public personDetailsFormModel: PersonDetailsFormModel;

    titles: Array<LabelValueItem>;
    biologicalSex: Array<LabelValueItem>;
    genderIdentities: Array<LabelValueItem>;
    alternativeEmailArr :Array<boolean>;
    controls: Array<FormControlDefinition>;
    emailMaxLength = 200;
    public localFormArrayName: string;
    public firstName: string;
    public personalEmail : string;
    public alternativeEmail : string;

    private dateOfBirthSubscription: Subscription;
    private biologicalSexSubscription: Subscription;
    private submitSubscription: Subscription;
    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        public olaBroadcastService: OlaBroadcastService,
        public genericBroadcastService: GenericBroadcastService,
        public broadcastService: BroadcastService,
        public appFormStore: AppFormStore,
        public contentService: ContentService,
        public appRuntimeService: AppRuntimeService,
        public navigationStore: NavigationStore,
        private _scrollToService: ScrollToService) {
        this.submitSubscription = this.genericBroadcastService.submitted.subscribe(n => {
            this.expandInvalidPersons();
        });
    }

    // -------------------FormControl Fieldnames-------------------
    private Partner = 'Partner';
    private Children = 'Children';

    ngOnInit() {
        this.localFormArrayName = this.personType === PERSON_TYPE_PARTNER ? this.Partner : this.Children;

        if (!this.form) {
            // this.form = this.fb.group({});
        }

        if (!this.maxAllowedErrorMessage) {
            this.maxAllowedErrorMessage = 'Only ' + this.maxAllowedPersons + ' persons are allowed.';
        }
        this.loadTitles();
        this.loadBiologicalSex();
        this.loadGenderIdentities();
        this.buildForm();
    }

    public buildForm() {
        let personGroups = new Array<FormGroup>();

        if (this.persons) {
            personGroups = this.persons.map(person => this.fb.group(person));
            for (let i = 0; i < personGroups.length; i++) {
                this.applyValidators(personGroups[i]);
                this.emitGroupChanges(personGroups[i]);

                if(!this.persons[i].isNew){
                    for(const field in personGroups[i].controls){
                        personGroups[i].controls[field].disable();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        const personFormArray = this.fb.array(personGroups);
        this.form.addControl(this.localFormArrayName, personFormArray);
        personFormArray.setValidators(Validators.maxLength(this.maxAllowedPersons));

        // expand person invalid data straight away
        personGroups.forEach((per: FormGroup, i:number) => {
            if (per.invalid || this.isAddedMember(i)) {
                per.get('expanded').setValue(true);
            }
        });
    }

    get personCount() {
        return this.persons.length;
    }

    get personsArray(): FormArray {
        if (!this.form) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.form.get(this.localFormArrayName) as FormArray;
    }

public get showChemoAgeMessage(): boolean {
        const plan = AppFormHelper.GetApplicantHealthInsurance(this.appform.PolicyHolder);
        if(!plan){
            return false;
        }
        const age = this.appform.Constants.ChemoAgeThreshold;
        const stepHelper: IStepHelper = StepHelperFactory.createStepHelper(this.navigationStore);
        const existingChemoSubmodule = plan.PlanSubModule;
        let appform = AppFormClone.getAppFormClone(this.appform);
        const formModel = this.form.getRawValue();
        if (formModel != null) {
            // update with current form
            if (stepHelper) {
                appform = stepHelper.updateAppForm(appform, formModel, null);
            }
        }

        const chemoSubModules = existingChemoSubmodule ? this.appform.PlanSubModuleConfigurationItems.filter(p => p.PlanSubModuleType == SubModuleTypes.Chemo) : [];
        const matchingSubModule = chemoSubModules.find(p => p.PlanSubModuleCode == existingChemoSubmodule);
        return matchingSubModule && AppFormHelper.hasOlderPartner(appform, age);
    }

    public get policyHolderOverAgeThreshold(): boolean {
        const age = this.appform.Constants.ChemoAgeThreshold;
        const stepHelper: IStepHelper = StepHelperFactory.createStepHelper(this.navigationStore);
        let appform = AppFormClone.getAppFormClone(this.appform);

        const formModel = this.form.getRawValue();
        if (formModel != null) {
            // update with current form
            if (stepHelper) {
                appform = stepHelper.updateAppForm(appform, formModel, null);
            }
        }

        return AppFormHelper.policyHolderOverAgeThreshold(appform, age);
    }

    public get partnerOverAgeThreshold(): boolean {
        const age = this.appform.Constants.ChemoAgeThreshold;
        const stepHelper: IStepHelper = StepHelperFactory.createStepHelper(this.navigationStore);
        let appform = AppFormClone.getAppFormClone(this.appform);

        const formModel = this.form.getRawValue();
        if (formModel != null) {
            // update with current form
            if (stepHelper) {
                appform = stepHelper.updateAppForm(appform, formModel, null);
            }
        }

        return AppFormHelper.partnerOverAgeThreshold(appform, age);
    }


    public ngOnDestroy() {
        // removing the validators when the control is hidden
        this.submitSubscription.unsubscribe();
        if (this.dateOfBirthSubscription) {
            this.dateOfBirthSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }

        if (this.biologicalSexSubscription) {
            this.biologicalSexSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    private loadTitles(): void {
        // initializing the titles
        this.titles = new Array<LabelValueItem>();
        this.titles.push(new LabelValueItem('Select', ''));
        for (let i = 0; i < Titles.ALL.length; i++) {
            this.titles.push(new LabelValueItem(Titles.ALL[i].label,
                Titles.ALL[i].key));
        }
    }

    private loadBiologicalSex(): void {
        // initializing the biological sex
        this.biologicalSex = new Array<LabelValueItem>();
        this.biologicalSex.push(new LabelValueItem('Select', ''));
        for (let i = 0; i < Genders.ALL.length; i++) {
            this.biologicalSex.push(new LabelValueItem(Genders.ALL[i].label,
                Genders.ALL[i].key));
        }
    }


    private loadGenderIdentities(): void {
        // initializing the gender identities
        this.genderIdentities = new Array<LabelValueItem>();
        this.genderIdentities.push(new LabelValueItem('Select', null));
        for (let i = 0; i < GenderIdentities.ALL.length; i++) {
            this.genderIdentities.push(new LabelValueItem(GenderIdentities.ALL[i].label,
                GenderIdentities.ALL[i].key));
        }
    }

    addPerson() {
        const newPerson = new Person(0, '', '', null, {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            middleNameInitial: ''
        }, true, null, 0,'','', null);
        newPerson.displayEmails = false;
        newPerson.hasAlternativeEmail = false;
        const personGroup = this.fb.group(newPerson);

        personGroup.get
        this.applyValidators(personGroup);
        personGroup.controls['alternativeEmail'].disable();
        this.personsArray.push(personGroup);
        this.emitGroupChanges(personGroup);
        this.onPersonalEmailChange(personGroup);
        // this.change.emit(Events.EVENTS.PersonAdded.value);
        this.broadcastService.cartDataUpdated.raise(
            new BroadcastEventArgs<FormGroup>(this.form, Events.EVENTS.PersonAdded.value));
        this.olaBroadcastService.gtmRefresh.raise([]);

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.scrollToTop(this.personTopQueryList.last);
        }, 150);
    }

    removePerson(index) {
        this.personsArray.removeAt(index);
        // this.change.emit(Events.EVENTS.PersonRemoved.value);
        this.broadcastService.cartDataUpdated.raise(
            new BroadcastEventArgs<FormGroup>(this.form, Events.EVENTS.PersonRemoved.value));

        // Gtm:
        const prefix = this.personType === PERSON_TYPE_PARTNER ? 'Partner' : 'Child' + (index + 1);
        GTMHelper.pushFieldChange('Removed ' + prefix, '', '');
    }

    public hasAlternativeEmail(personGroup)
    {
        personGroup.get('hasAlternativeEmail').setValue(true);
    }

    public addAlternativeEmail(personGroup)
    {
        personGroup.get('hasAlternativeEmail').setValue(true);
        personGroup.controls['alternativeEmail'].addValidators([Validators.required]);
        personGroup.controls['alternativeEmail'].enable();
    }

    public removeAlternativeEmail(personGroup) {
        personGroup.get('hasAlternativeEmail').setValue(false);
        personGroup.get('alternativeEmail').disable();
        personGroup.get('alternativeEmail').setValue('');
    }

    emailFocusOut(personGroup){
        if (personGroup.get('personalEmail').valid && personGroup.get('personalEmail').value) {
          var hashedEmail = sha256(personGroup.get('personalEmail').value);
          GTMHelper.pushUserIdChange(hashedEmail);
        }
      }

    alternativeEmailFocusOut(personGroup){
        if (personGroup.get('alternativeEmail').valid && personGroup.get('alternativeEmail').value) {
          var hashedEmail = sha256(personGroup.get('alternativeEmail').value);
          GTMHelper.pushUserIdChange(hashedEmail);
        }
    }

    isChild() {
        return this.personType === PERSON_TYPE_CHILD;
    }

    getHeading(nameModel, index): string {
        if (nameModel &&
            (nameModel.GivenName ||
                nameModel.MiddleNameInitial ||
                nameModel.FamilyName)) {
            const givenName = nameModel.GivenName || '';
            const middleName = nameModel.MiddleNameInitial || '';
            const lastName = nameModel.FamilyName || '';
            return givenName + ' ' + middleName + ' ' + lastName;
        }
        return this.maxAllowedPersons > 1 ? this.heading + ' ' + index : this.heading;
    }

    private applyValidators(personGroup:FormGroup): void {
        personGroup.get('biologicalSex').setValidators([Validators.required]);
        if (this.personType === PERSON_TYPE_PARTNER) {
            const v = CompareDatesValidator(this.constants.MaxSpouseAge, true, DOBValidationMessages.OLDER_THAN_MAX_AGE, true);
            personGroup.get('dateOfBirth').setValidators([v]);
        } else {
            const v = CompareDatesValidator(this.constants.MaxChildAge, true, DOBValidationMessages.CHILD_OLDER_THAN_21, true);
            personGroup.get('dateOfBirth').setValidators([v]);
        }

        personGroup.get('personalEmail').setValidators([
            Validators.maxLength(this.emailMaxLength),
            Validators.pattern(this.constants.EmailRegExPattern)
        ]);

        personGroup.get('alternativeEmail').setValidators([
            Validators.maxLength(this.emailMaxLength),
            Validators.pattern(this.constants.EmailRegExPattern)
        ]);
    }

    private expandInvalidPersons(): void {
        if (this.personsArray) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.personsArray.controls.length; i++) {
                const personGroup = this.personsArray.controls[i];
                personGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
                 if (personGroup.invalid) {
                    personGroup.get('expanded').setValue(true);
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    private emitGroupChanges(personGroup: FormGroup): void {
        this.dateOfBirthSubscription = personGroup.get('dateOfBirth').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
            if (this.isValidForTriggerShoppingCartEvents(personGroup)) {
                // this.change.emit(Events.EVENTS.DateOfBirthUpdated.value);
                this.broadcastService.cartDataUpdated.raise(
                    new BroadcastEventArgs<FormGroup>(this.form, Events.EVENTS.DateOfBirthUpdated.value));
            }
        });

      this.biologicalSexSubscription = personGroup.get('biologicalSex').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
        if (this.isValidForTriggerShoppingCartEvents(personGroup)) {
          // this.change.emit(Events.EVENTS.GenderUpdated.value);
          this.broadcastService.cartDataUpdated.raise(
              new BroadcastEventArgs<FormGroup>(this.form, Events.EVENTS.GenderUpdated.value));
        }
      });
    }

    private isValidForTriggerShoppingCartEvents(personGroup: FormGroup): boolean {
        return true;  // the subscription for 'cartDataUpdated' handles whether or not there is dobs etc

        // let isValid = personGroup.get('dateOfBirth').valid && personGroup.get('biologicalSex').valid;
        // if (personGroup.controls['applicantResponses']) {
        //     const smokingControl = personGroup.controls['applicantResponses'] as FormGroup;
        //         isValid = isValid && smokingControl.controls[0].valid;
        // }
        // return isValid;
    }

    onNameChange(nameForm: FormGroup) {
        // this.change.emit(Events.EVENTS.NameUpdated.value);
        this.broadcastService.cartDataUpdated.raise(
            new BroadcastEventArgs<FormGroup>(this.form, Events.EVENTS.NameUpdated.value));
        if (nameForm.get && nameForm.get('GivenName')) { // observed it coming through as a plain-jane event
            this.firstName = (nameForm.get('GivenName') as any).value;
        }
    }
    onNameTextChange(v: LabelValueItem, idx: number) {
        const prefix = this.personType === PERSON_TYPE_PARTNER ? 'Partner' : 'Child' + (idx + 1);
        const nme = prefix + '-' + v.label;
        GTMHelper.pushFieldChange(nme, v.label, '');
    }
    public isValidSmokingAge(personGroup: FormGroup) {
        if (!this.firstName) {
            this.firstName = this.personType;
        }

        const minAge = this.healthData.Constants.MinSmokingAge;
        const dob = personGroup.controls['dateOfBirth'] ? personGroup.controls['dateOfBirth'].value : null;
        const age = personGroup.controls['age'] ? personGroup.controls['age'].value : 0;
        return HealthHelper.isValidSmokingAge(minAge, dob, age);
    }

    // Determines if we can show the link to add an additional plan
    public canAddPlan(personGroup: FormGroup) {
        if (!this.policyHolderAdditionalPlanName) {
            return false;
        }
        // show the link if the person doesn't have the additional plan and they've filled in the details
        return !personGroup.get('additionalPlanName').value && !personGroup.invalid;
    }

    // Determines if we can show the link to remove an additional plan
    public canRemovePlan(personGroup: FormGroup) {
        //  remove link not to be shown
        return false;
        /* if (!this.policyHolderAdditionalPlanName)
            return false;
        // show the link if the person doesn't have the additional plan and they've filled in the details
        return personGroup.get('additionalPlanName').value && personGroup.valid;*/
    }
    isPersonDisabled(index:number){
        if(this.persons && this.persons[index]){
            return !this.persons[index].isNew;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    isAddedMember(index:number){
        if(this.persons && this.persons[index]){
            if(this.appform.ApplicationSource == ApplicationSource.OnlineAppExistingMember){
                return this.persons[index].isNew;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public gotoCover() {
        const step = this.appRuntimeService.Steps[ROUTENAME_COVER];
        this.olaBroadcastService.validateAndNavigate.raise(step);
    }
    onSmokerChange(personGroup: FormGroup) {
        if (this.isValidForTriggerShoppingCartEvents(personGroup)) {
            // this.change.emit(Events.EVENTS.HealthyLifeStyleUpdated.value);
            this.broadcastService.cartDataUpdated.raise(
                new BroadcastEventArgs<FormGroup>(this.form, Events.EVENTS.HealthyLifeStyleUpdated.value));
        }
    }

    onDobChanged(val: any, personGroup: FormGroup) {
        const enableDobValidation = personGroup.controls['enableDobValidation'];
        if (val) {
            if (val.date) {
                enableDobValidation.setValue(true);
                this.displayEmails(val.date,personGroup);
            } else if (val.type && val.type === 'change') {
                if (val.srcElement && val.srcElement.classList.contains('invaliddate')) {
                    enableDobValidation.setValue(true);
                } else {
                    if (personGroup.get('dateOfBirth').value) {
                        enableDobValidation.setValue(true);
                    } else {
                        enableDobValidation.setValue(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            enableDobValidation.setValue(false);
        }
    }

    onPersonalEmailChange(personGroup: FormGroup)
    {
        if(personGroup.get('personalEmail').value == "")
        {
            this.removeAlternativeEmail(personGroup);
        }
    }

    displayEmails(dob,personGroup: FormGroup)
    {
        const s = moment(dob.month + '-' + dob.day + '-' + dob.year, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
        const isValid = AppFormHelper.isOverCiCaAgeThreshold(s, this.constants.ValidEmailCaptureAge);
        if (!isValid)
        {
            personGroup.get('personalEmail').setValue('');
            this.removeAlternativeEmail(personGroup);
        }
        if (personGroup.get("displayEmails"))
        {
            personGroup.get("displayEmails").setValue(isValid);
        }
    }

    showCancerAssistLimitMessage(personGroup: FormGroup): boolean {
        if (this.policyHolderAdditionalPlanName) {
            const appForm = this.appFormStore.appform;

                if (this.policyHolderAdditionalPlanName.toLocaleString().search('Cancer Assist') === -1 ||
                (this.personType !== PERSON_TYPE_PARTNER || !(AppFormHelper.isCAOrCI(appForm.PolicyHolder, appForm.Spouse)))) {
                    return false;
                }

                const ctrl = personGroup.get('dateOfBirth') || personGroup.get('DateOfBirth');
                const dob = ctrl.value;
                if (dob) {
                    const dt = dob.date;
                    const s = moment(dt.month + '-' + dt.day + '-' + dt.year, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
                    return AppFormHelper.isOverCiCaAgeThreshold(s, appForm.Constants.CiCaAgeThreshold);
                }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    showCriticalIllnessLimitMessage(personGroup: FormGroup): boolean {
        if (this.policyHolderAdditionalPlanName) {
            const appForm = this.appFormStore.appform;

            if (this.policyHolderAdditionalPlanName.toLocaleString().search('Critical Illness') === -1 ||
            (this.personType !== PERSON_TYPE_PARTNER || !(AppFormHelper.isCAOrCI(appForm.PolicyHolder, appForm.Spouse)))) {
                return false;
            }
            const ctrl = personGroup.get('dateOfBirth') || personGroup.get('DateOfBirth');
            const dob = ctrl.value;
            if (dob) {
                const dt = dob.date;
                const s = moment(dt.month + '-' + dt.day + '-' + dt.year, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
                return AppFormHelper.isOverCiCaAgeThreshold(s, appForm.Constants.CiCaAgeThreshold);
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    scrollToTop(personTop) {
        const isMobile = !UIHelper.isHidden(this.divMobile.nativeElement);

        if (personTop && personTop.nativeElement) {
            this.olaBroadcastService.collapseHeader.raise('scroll');
            UIHelper.scrollToElementScrollService(
                personTop.nativeElement, this._scrollToService, 'easeInOutQuad', 1000, isMobile ? 175 : 0);
        }
    }

    toggleExpand(personGroup: FormGroup, index: any) {
        personGroup.get('expanded').setValue(!personGroup.get('expanded').value);

        const expanded = personGroup.get('expanded').value;
        if (expanded) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.scrollToTop(this.personTopQueryList.toArray()[index]);
            }, 150);
        }
    }

    public getChemoAgeMessage(): string {
        if (this.policyHolderOverAgeThreshold && this.partnerOverAgeThreshold) {
            return this.contentService.getContent(ContentKeys.PERSON_CHEMO_OVER_60_BOTH);
        } else if (this.partnerOverAgeThreshold) {
            return this.contentService.getContent(ContentKeys.PERSON_CHEMO_OVER_60_PARTNER);
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

person-input html code as follow (the changes should be in AddPerson? I just provide all the code just in case anyone wants to have some background idea)

```
<div class="person-input" [formGroup]="form" [class.submitted]="submitted">
    <div [formArrayName]="localFormArrayName" [class.submitted]="submitted">
        <div class="striped accordion chevron-right" id="accordion">
            <div *ngFor="let personGroup of personsArray.controls; let i=index" [class.addedmember]="isAddedMember(i)">
                <div [formGroupName]="i" class="item" [class.dashed]="((i+1) < personsArray.controls.length || forceDottedLine)" [id]="localFormArrayName + i.toString()" #personTop>
                    <div class="form-group item-heading">
                        <a [class.collapsed]="!personGroup.get('expanded').value" (click)="toggleExpand($any(personGroup), i);">

                            <ng-container *ngIf="personGroup.get('NameForm')" >
                              <div class="h1 collapse-heading">{{getHeading(personGroup.get('NameForm').value, i + 1)}}</div>
                            </ng-container>

                            <div class="collapse-text hidden-xs">{{personGroup.get('expanded').value? 'Collapse' : 'Expand'}}</div>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse" [class.in]="personGroup.get('expanded').value" [@accordion300]="personGroup.get('expanded').value? '*' : 'void'">
                        <div class="item-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="header-container">
                                    <div class="title-container">
                                        <h3>Personal details</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="remove-container">
                                        <a *ngIf="!isPersonDisabled(i)" (click)="removePerson(i)" title="Remove this person" class="remove-option-container">
                                            <span class="remove-label">Remove</span>
                                            <span class="remove-icon icon circle-md info cross-white"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Title (optional)</label>
                                <drop-down formControlName="salutation" [items]="titles" [submitted]="submitted" class="salutation"></drop-down>
                                <div *ngIf="personGroup.get('salutation').invalid && submitted" class="error">Select a salutation</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                                <name-input [disabled]="isPersonDisabled(i)" autofocus [name]="personGroup.get('name').value" [form]="$any(personGroup)" [submitted]="submitted" (change)="onNameChange($event)" (textChange)="onNameTextChange($event, i)" autofocus></name-input>
                            </div>
```

I've tried to use
personGroup.get('name')?
personGroup.controls['name'].setvalue('focused')= true
didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution
in person-input.html

I added

```
<name-input [disabled]="isPersonDisabled(i)" [focused]="isAddedPersonClicked" [name]="personGroup.get('name').value" [form]="$any(personGroup)" [submitted]="submitted" (change)="onNameChange($event)" (textChange)="onNameTextChange($event, i)" autofocus></name-input>
                            </div>
```

in person-input.ts I added

```
isAddPersonClicked = false;
```

and set isAddPersonClicked to true if every single time a person is being added

```
addPerson() {
    const newPerson = new Person(0, '', '', null, {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        middleNameInitial: ''
    }, true, null, 0,'','', null);
    newPerson.displayEmails = false;
    newPerson.hasAlternativeEmail = false;
    const personGroup = this.fb.group(newPerson);
    this.isAddPersonClicked = true;

    personGroup.get
    this.applyValidators(personGroup);
    personGroup.controls['alternativeEmail'].disable();
    this.personsArray.push(personGroup);
    this.emitGroupChanges(personGroup);
    this.onPersonalEmailChange(personGroup);
    // this.change.emit(Events.EVENTS.PersonAdded.value);
    this.broadcastService.cartDataUpdated.raise(
        new BroadcastEventArgs<FormGroup>(this.form, Events.EVENTS.PersonAdded.value));
    this.olaBroadcastService.gtmRefresh.raise([]);

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.scrollToTop(this.personTopQueryList.last);
    }, 150);
}
```

so now my page will be showing focus on given name of policy holder if there is more than 1 spouse of child being added at the same page
and when the spouse or childen area in appended it will be focused on "given name" too

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too long and complicated, can't read them all. But here is some idea I have for you.
You're wanting to modify value of a parent component's property in the child component, right?

Let's call parent component is A and the child is B. A have a field called 'name', you would like to change 'name' value in component B. In this case you could use EventEmitter to handle this ([Angular - EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)).

Not sure if this could help. It would be great if your question is concise.

Comment: Thanks so much i'll have a look, pretty much the code should be in "AddPerson" to make the changes of field change of "name" but i just provide all the information just in case. thanks